# Need to edit a vertical row but not the entire UNC path data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a vertical row called ImgPath
It has data like this `\\svrju01\pcss\images\Case 00004.2009\P1A8.doc`

This point to an UNC path were our PDF documents reside. I want to move this data to another server and need to point the unc path, to the new server. While keeping the other UNC path data untouched.

So as it stands

```
\\svrju01\pcss\images\Case 00004.2009\P1A8.doc
```

and change it to this

```
\\cjd-jems01\pcss\images\Case 00004.2009\P1A8.doc
```

Exactly like that. Down the row. Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thank you so much for any assistance.

Comment: It's called string parsing.  Google "SQL String Functions".

Comment: On a test copy; `update tbl set fld = replace(fld, '\\svrju01\', '\\cjd-jems01\')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the simple replace command like below -

DATA SETUP -

```
create table working (id int identity(1,1), [Name] varchar(20), [Path] varchar(300) )

insert into working ([Name], [Path]) values ('Murtaza', '\\ABC\data\test\folder\cc90292.doc')
insert into working ([Name], [Path]) values ('Murtaza', '\\ABC\data\test\folder\cc90293.doc')
insert into working ([Name], [Path]) values ('Murtaza', '\\ABC\data\test\folder\cc90295.doc')
insert into working ([Name], [Path]) values ('Murtaza', '\\ABC\data\test\folder\cc90296.doc')
insert into working ([Name], [Path]) values ('Murtaza', '\\ABC\data\test\folder\cc90298.doc')
```

QUERY TO LOAD THE DATA -

```
select [Name], replace([path], '\\ABC', '\\PQR') as [path] from working
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/709fcb/1)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys. i got it

This one is the winner
 On a test copy; update tbl set fld = replace(fld, '\svrju01\', '\cjd-jems01\') –  Alex K. 6 hours ago

But you must right click the table, and select UPDATE